# Oracle SQLclをバッチで実行するには

Tags: sql, oracle

Windows環境でOracle SQLclを使ってテーブルデータをCSVファイルに出力するために下記のバッチファイルを書きましたが、データベースへのアクセス以外はうまくゆきません。
正しい書き方をご教授ください。

```
@echo off
echo set sqlformat csv ^
echo set heading off feedback off ^
echo spool c:\PIYO.csv ^
echo select * from PIYO ^
echo spool off | C:\sqlcl\bin\sql -L user/password@//172.16.xx.xxx:1521/HOGE.FUGA
```

対話式で下記のように実行するとCSVファイルが出力されます。

```
cd C:\sqlcl\bin
sql user/password@//172.16.xx.xxx:1521/HOGE.FUGA
SQL> set sqlformat csv
SQL> set heading off feedback off
SQL> spool c:\PIYO.csv
SQL> select * from PIYO;
SQL> spool off
```

[本家Stack Overflowの解決策](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47038000/sqlcl-batch-scripting-auto-connection-export-csv)を参考にしてバッチファイルを書きました。

Answer (score 1):

本家の解決策と比べて `^&` が抜けてます。

```
@echo off
echo set sqlformat csv ^& ^
echo set heading off feedback off ^& ^
echo spool c:\PIYO.csv ^& ^
echo select * from PIYO ^& ^
echo spool off | C:\sqlcl\bin\sql -L user/password@//172.16.xx.xxx:1521/HOGE.FUGA
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。^&を外してテストしたときのソースをアップしてしまいました。^&が入っていても同じ状況です。

Comment: そうでしたか。ちなみに「うまくいかない」と書かれてますが、どううまく言ってないのか エラーが出ているとかなど、具体的に教えていただけますか？